# Database connection error (2): Could not connect to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am getting this error on my Joomla site.

Please note:

- I have checked configuration file and there is no error in it.
- I get this error few times a day. Without making any change it gets connected and some time this error appears.

Can someone please help in this.

Thanks
Dani

Comment: Check if your mySQL server is not restarting, or under heavy load, or has a low connection count limit.

Comment: it would help to describe the load on the system

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. How do I check if MYSQL server is not restarting please?

Comment: When I  add special URL character  a period end of the URL , I got the same message which you got.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the MySQL server is overloaded, and so it stops responding. If you are on a shared hosting, then you should ask to be moved to a less crowded server. If you are on a VPS (with a fair use policy) or on a dedicated server, then you should enable and check the slow query log for the slow queries causing your MySQL server to crash.